# apportable release key for distribution....

Tags: apportable

I am so close.
It is incredible that Apportable actually works so well, pretty amazing.

I can't get the absolute last step finalized.  I am about ready to scream.

How do I get a valid signed key.....  Does anyone have any hints on how this works.....

I know where all the files are located, but it won't sign the final release build.  And I can't upload to google play.  Any hints would be great.

Release keys

The debug key that is automatically generated by the Apportable SDK and stored in your ~/.android folder should not be used for publishing release to app stores. Generate a release key using the following command.

keytool -genkey -v -keystore release.keystore -alias mykey -keyalg RSA \
        -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
To make a build using the release keystore, make sure that the ANDROID_KEYSTORE environment variable is pointing to the path to the release keystore and set ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASS to the keystore password you used. Don't forget to set BUILD to "release" as well. It should look something like this:

BUILD=release ANDROID_KEYSTORE=release.keystore \
        ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASS=mypassword apportable build
The release APK that you need to upload is in ~/.apportable/SDK/ and the exact path will appear on the command line.

Make sure to store your release.keystore file in a safe place. We cannot recover it for you and if you lose it, you will not be able to update your app.

Comment: What happens when you run the keytool program? Or where do the instructions fail for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yu may just follow the steps in the document and export the environment variables to the console when start to build.

You may keep the alias of the key as 'mykey'. I once changed the alias to other value and it did not work out.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To make a release mode build with stripped symbols, the BUILD environment should be set on the command line, like this:

BUILD=release apportable load

http://docs.apportable.com/publishing